# poner función php en un checkbox

Tags: php, html

Buenas trato de poner una función a un checkbox pero la forma en que lo necesito es algo "compleja" no se como llamarlo el punto es que estoy haciendo que php escriba mi consulta en un bucle dependiendo de la consulta a la base de datos por lo tanto si tengo 30 registros el bucle while lo "dibujara" 30 veces los inputs que sean necesarios pero ahora necesito que un checkbox este marcado cuando la consulta en la base de datos sea verdadera, por ejemplo ese checkbox se debe marcar siempre y cuando en la base de datos ya exista un registro de "flujo mayor" de no se asi pues no marca el checkbox y esta función la quiero lograr con un if

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='flujo_mayor".$row['id']."' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='".$row['flujo_mayor']."' ".if ($row['flujo_mayor']=='Flujo Mayor') {'checked'}."></td>";
```

Comment: ¿Y porqué mejor no crear una variable de tipo cadena que tome el valor `checked` si la consulta es verdadera y carácter nulo (`""`) si es falsa y luego simplemente concatenarla en tu salida?

Comment: gracias @MauricioContreras me base en tu comentario para hacerlo , puedes verificar la respuesta para ver si es eso a lo que te referías.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo, prueba esto:

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='flujo_mayor".$row['id']."' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='".$row['flujo_mayor']."' ".$row['flujo_mayor']=='Flujo Mayor'? 'checked':''."></td>";
```

---

Puedes comparar con ? directamente en un **echo**

```
$valor="Flujo Mayor";
echo $valor=="Flujo Mayor" ? "BUENO":"MALO";
```

//Resultado: Bueno

Comment: Tienes la reputación suficiente para saber [answer], al menos una breve explicación de tu código y del operador condicional ternario seria una mejora bienvenida a tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Justo la estaba editando para poner un ejemplo offtopic :) Gracias igual bro

Answer (score 0):

decidí que talvez es mejor poner por un lado la parte de la lógica y no agregarlo directamente a la parte de `echo` así que hice un `if` de la siguiente manera :

```
          if ($row['flujo_menor'] === 'Flujo Menor') {
              $checked0 = 'checked="checked" ';
              } else {
                 $checked0 = ' ';
              }
```

y luego con el resultado que esto me genere atreves de la consulta ponelro directamente en el echo como variable

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='flujo_menor".$row['id']."' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='".$row['flujo_menor']."' echo $checked0></td>";
```

nótese que la parte que marca el chekbox o hace el cambio es la mimas variable con código html `echo $checked0`